# int divided by int to make a BigDecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal, integer-division

Is it possible to divide two integers to make and make a BigDecimal out of it? I'm attempting to optimize my code. If I could reduce the number of times I declared a new BigDecimal, it should speed up my process significantly. As of now, the most I know I how to reduce my calculation is to:

```
BigDecimal tester = new BigDecimal("103993")
       .divide(new BigDecimal("33102"), 2000, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN);
```

I was wondering if it is possible to do something like this:

```
int example1 = 103993;
int example2 = 33102;

BigDecimal example3 = example1/example2;
```

Or something along those lines. My only goal is to speed up execution time.

Comment: Don't fall into the trap of premature optimization. Until you profile your code (and actually have a problem) you have no idea what will cost you time.

Comment: I'm not sure there's any other way than to convert both to `BigDecimal` first. So optimization is moot...

Comment: I believe that is your only option, also one question is this for codechef?

Comment: Since you are using integers as arguments you don't need to use `BigDecimal(String s)` constructor, but just `BigDecimal(int i)`. This way application wont have to parse String to numeric value.

Comment: @Pshemo `valueOf` is a much better alternative to the constructor because `BigDecimal` "potentially" (it does) retains a bucket of certain values that it can simply return rather than reconstructing.  The same can be said for all of the `Number` formats as well.

Comment: @pickypg Yes, you are right. I just tried to point out that in situations where we have precise number (no floating point issue) there is no need to use constructor with String argument and make app convert it to that value again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a slight improvement that you can do that uses the [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)'s internal cache by using its [`valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf%28long%29) method:

```
BigDecimal.valueOf(example1).divide(
    BigDecimal.valueOf(example2), 2000, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN);
```

Answer (score 2):

In a word, no. By the time you've divided one `int` by the other, you've already lost information.